# How to type React Component whose props get partially applied?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function that takes a React component and partially applies its props. This is used e.g. to supply a component with a theme from a consumer.

It basically converts this `<FancyComponent theme="black" text="blah"/>` to this `<AlreadyFanciedComponent text="blah"/>`, which is the same component just with the `theme` already provided.

I cannot work out how this has to be typed.

Here is some working code throwing TypeScript errors:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ComponentType } from "react";


type Theme = {theme: string};

function preTheme<TProps extends Theme>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<TProps>) {
    return React.forwardRef<typeof WrappedComponent, TProps>((props: TProps, ref) => {
        // here could be a Consumer
        return <WrappedComponent theme={props.theme} ref={ref} {...props} />
    })
}

const ThemedP: React.FC<{theme: string, text: string}> = props => <p className={props.theme}>{props.text}</p>;
const PreThemedP = preTheme(ThemedP);

ReactDOM.render(<PreThemedP text={"Here be useless text"}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The error is: `Property 'theme' is missing in type '{ text: string; }' but required in type '{ theme: string; text: string; }'`

[Here it is in a playground.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-fmxwu?file=/src/index.tsx:0-689)

Comment: *"It basically converts this `<FancyComponent theme="black" text="blah"/>` to this `<FancyComponent text="blah"/>`."* But with a different identifier, right?

Comment: *What* TypeScript errors? The sandbox link just complains `Cannot find module 'react'` etc., and the [mre] needs to be *in the question*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. Edited.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It takes some time for the page to load. Otherwise the same code is provided in the post.

Comment: Yes, that loaded eventually, but the appropriate information still needs to be in the question. I think you just want `Omit<TProps, "theme">`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, but I'm not sure where exactly to put it. It always resulted in errors.

Edit: The error was added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) the `theme` property from the props of the wrapped component:

```
return React.forwardRef<typeof WrappedComponent, Omit<TProps, "theme">>(...);
```